# Difference between Earth's surface area seen from ISS and the theoretical area if light refraction is neglected

Tags: visible-light, astronomy, refraction, earth

What is the difference between Earth's surface area seen from ISS and the theoretical area if light refraction is neglected? I watched a video telling that it is not possible to know why a great portion of Earth surface is visible for astronauts from a distance of 400km as it should be visible only a small portion though. If somebody knows something about this question any answer is welcome.

Comment: Which video? Also take a look at the [NASA live stream from the ISS](https://youtu.be/86YLFOog4GM) it's very apparent that they can only see a small (but quickly moving) bit of earth.

Answer (score 0):

> I watched a video ...

Never believe what you see on YouTube. It is true that only a small portion of the Earth's surface is visible from the ISS *at any one time* (and refraction of light will make only a very small difference to this). However, the orbit of the ISS is inclined at an angle of over $50^\text{o}$ to the equator. So, as the ISS orbits and the Earth rotates beneath it, all of the Earth's surface between latitudes of about $55^\text{o}$ S and $55^\text{o}$ N is visible from the ISS at one time or another.